# JQuery animate slower every call

Tags: jquery, performance, jquery-animate

I have a modal box I open with Jquery. When the close buttons is called, the modal box is closed. All works fine, but the more I open and close the modal box, the longer it takes for the modal box to close:

```
window.closeModal = function () {
    modal = $("div.modal-overlay");
    windowHeight = $(window).height();
    // Until here performance is good
    modal.animate({top: windowHeight, }, 800, function () {
        // This is the problem 
        modal.hide();
        $("body").css("overflow-y", "scroll");
    });
}
```

I have put console logs on every line, and everything is executed instantly until I hit the modal.animate function. Every time I open a modal, and press the close button, it takes more time until modal.animate starts executing.

Can anyone shed some light please.

@EDIT:
I have created a jsfiddle that shows the problem.

Just press open modal, then close modal. Do this **4-5** times to see the delay become bigger

http://jsfiddle.net/CZ54C/

@@EDIT: Something very strange happens.

although openModal is executed once, the iframe.load is executed # times the modal is opened and closed ...

```
window.openModal = function (url) {
    console.log("open start");
    modal = $("div.modal-overlay");
    modalIframe = $("div.modal-overlay iframe");
    windowHeight = $(window).height();
    modal.css("bottom", "0");
    modalIframe.attr("src", url + "?frame=true");
    modalIframe.load(function () {
        console.log("open load")
        modalIframe.css('height', windowHeight);
        modal.show().animate({
            top: 0,
        }, 800, function () {
            $("body").css("overflow-y", "hidden");
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Try reducing the duration( 800 to 400) to complete the animation bit faster..

Comment: lol @web2008 - it takes longer each time he does it.  It's not just too slow!!

Comment: @Archer,exactly. It's not that the animation gets stacked because the animation is long done after the new one is triggered.

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue in jsfiddle or jsbin?

Comment: Did you try doing stop animation before starting another one ? http://api.jquery.com/stop/

Comment: @Nealv based on your jsfiddle. I think it could also be because of the load time of the iframe. Also try this out. Does it fix it :- http://jsfiddle.net/MNN7q/

Comment: @MarutiB, your jsfiddle is exactly the same as mine. I don't think it is because of the load, because the delay happens when closing the window, not opening it.

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved the problem,

It seems that by changing the iframe url, the "load handler gets attached again". So every time the "load is executed', it is attached. I solved it by using this code:

```
 modalIframe.one('load',function () {});

//Instad of
 modalIframe.load(function () {});
```

Is this good practice ?

Comment: This wouldn't work for you because the `one` function will remove the handler after it has been called once. That means the handler will not be called after you click the "Open modal" link for the first time. See my answer for a better solution.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me; try opening, closing, then opening the modal again in this example using `one`: http://jsfiddle.net/CZ54C/3/

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are attaching a new `load` handler to the `modalIframe` every time you open the modal dialog. So if you this the second time you've clicked "Open modal", the load callback will be executed two times. On the next click, it will be executed three times and so on.

The best way to approach this is move the load event handler outside the `openModal` function into the same block where you attach your click handlers:

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/CZ54C/2/)

```
$(function () {
    var modal = $("div.modal-overlay"),
        modalIframe = modal.find('iframe');

    $("a.open").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var href = $(this).attr("href");
        openModal(href);
    });

    $("a.close").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        closeModal();
    });

    //put load handler here
    modalIframe.load(function () {
        var windowHeight = $(window).height();

        modalIframe.css('height', windowHeight);
        modal.show().animate({
            top: 0,
        }, 800, function () {
            $("body").css("overflow-y", "hidden");
        });
    });
});

window.openModal = function (url) {
    $("div.modal-overlay iframe").attr("src", url + "?frame=true");
}

window.closeModal = function () {
    modal = $("div.modal-overlay");
    windowHeight = $(window).height();
    modal.animate({
        top: windowHeight,
    }, 800, function () {
        modal.hide();
        $("body").css("overflow-y", "scroll");
    });
}
```

Comment: The problem is that in my code, the load handler allready gets executed on page load. so without clicking a link, the modal is opened.

Comment: Are you doing that with a call to `openModal`? If so, it shouldn't make a difference so long as you are calling it after the `load` handler has been attached (i.e., in your jQuery ready callback)